# Why are function transformations inversed in equation form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, coordinate-systems, transformation

I recently came across this topic in math, about function and transformations.

For example:

Let's say I have a function $f(x) = x^2$

If I want to shift the function 3 units to the right, I need to subtract the $x$-value in the equation by $3$, this is counterintuitive to the way I would think: add $3$ to the function.

The equation becomes:

$f(x-3)=(x-3)^2$

And surprisingly not $f(x+3)=(x+3)^2$

Anyone could explain to me why is this the case?

Comment: The first step to gain so intuition is to plug in some values. Plug in $x = 0,1,2,3,\dots$ and try to understand what these values mean.

Comment: Yes, if I plug in the $x$-values from the graph, the equation does seem to hold true, but is this the only possible explanation, or is there a more concrete way?

Comment: See [How does one explain that transformations 'inside' a function operate in the opposite direction than intuition suggests?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/5614/745) (has 14 answers, 1 of which has been deleted)

Comment: Take note that shifting a function to the right is equivalent to shifting its inverse upwards. for $x\ge h$, consider:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{y}+h &=x\\
\sqrt{y} &= x-h\\
y &= (x-h)^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Compare the function $$g(x)=(x-3)^2$$ with $$f(x)=x^2$$

Note that $$ g(x+3)=f(x)$$
That is we have to move our $x$ three units to the right to get the same values out of the $g$